# Odd font size issue on only my website

Tags: css, font-size

I'm currently developing a site for my University's library, and a very strange issue came up. The font on the website, whether the live version or the one on my machine (not the server) is always smaller than it should be. This is only the case on two computers--my own, and my supervisor. It happens in all browsers. I'm pretty sure it's happening on both of ours because we've handled code, but I can't think of any CSS rules that would be affecting it. To make it worse, it's affecting two different CSSs--the old site (which I have not touched) and the new site which is intended to be rolled out tomorrow. I've tried fixing the way the computer displays fonts, the way browsers display fonts, changed the resolution, and tried zooming in. None of those methods worked. Also, other computers with the same resolution and monitors look at it just fine. No other websites that I visit have this issue. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

The site is here: http://library.uis.edu

Comparisons of the text can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3dRo.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a font issue, rather then a font size issue. Myriad pro is not considered a websave font. As your machine and probabaly the one of your supervisor have probabaly Adobe installed, wich comes with Myriad, you are seeing the site in Myriad, while the other machines are seeing the site in Verdana. (not entirely sure though)

Comment: It was a good thought--but unfortunately after uninstalling all Adobe products save Flash, the issue remains.

Comment: (Drastic solution, I would rather kick Flash and keep the rest. ;-) ) Did you check your font library? Is the Myriad actualy removed? You could also try removing the Myriad Pro from the font-family in your css to see if it has effect on the 'failing' machines.

Comment: Yes, there is no "Myriad" anymore--just "Myriad Arabic," "Myriad Hebrew," and "Myriad Pro". Unfortunately, deleting Myriad Pro is the very last thing I'd like to attempt, especially when the problem has only occurred recently and the fonts were added months ago.

Comment: I did actualy mean Myriad Pro, not Myriad, sorry. Myriad Pro is what you are targeting in your css. Did you try removing it from your css as i suggested?

Comment: Ah, oops. Yes, after trying that, it looks much better. In fact, looking at it closer, it seems like it's natively picking up Verdana on the other machines, not Myriad Pro. I'm going to try getting a different font pack for it tomorrow (or just delete it entirely), as my supervisor is currently glaring at me and seems like she would really like to leave.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling Myriad Pro as the first font. I have that font installed on my system, but you're calling the font size to be 75%, which on a font like Myriad Pro, will shrink it down considerably. If I clear the font-size, and font-family to just Verdana, it renders okay, but some of your elements such as the tabbed nav, would need to be addressed.

I'd stay away from fonts like that unless you are using @font-face and a web generated font pack. By choosing Myriad Pro as your font, you will only render that font on computers that also have the font. Consider using something like Google Web Fonts: http://www.google.com/webfonts/

Having fonts at the body level is fine, and cross fonts (headings versus paragraph) should be handled at a global level for those elements (not the body). Assume the body will take the bulk of the text in the body. You can define a standard font size such as 1.0em; at the body level if you wanted, and then define em sizes for other elements such as h1, h2 tags, and p tags if you don't want to use 1.0em from the body.

Comment: While your answer might make sense if it was happening across _all_ machines, it doesn't explain why only two machines are having issues.

Comment: It does in the sense that only your machine and the other would contain Myriad Pro. All other machines that you view the site on, wouldn't have that font installed.